# Merge modules in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, module

In my code, an array is declared from an imported module. Functions related to this module are imported from a second module. Here is a simplified version of my code:

**First module with the array**

```
let module1 = {};
module1.array = [10, 20, 30];
```

**Second module with the functions**

```
var module2 = {};
module2.fct1 = () => { return array[0]; };
module2.fct2 = () => { return array[1]; };
module2.fct3 = () => { return array[2]; };
```

I would like to merge the two modules to gets a single entity:

```
module1.fct1 = module2.fct1;
module1.fct2 = module2.fct2;
module1.fct3 = module2.fct3;
```

`module1` now contains the array and the functions

```
{
  array: [10, 20, 30],
  fct1: () => { return array[0];    },
  fct2: () => { return array[1];    },
  fct3: () => { return array[2];    }
}
```

But, when I call the function, the array seems not to be in the scope of the functions:

```
console.log (module1.fct1())
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined

If I create a single module with the array and the function in the same file, it works.

My question is : is there a way to merge two modules in JavaScript. My final goal is to pass the merged modules to another function.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/rxsfvgda/4/

Comment: `fct1: () => { return this.array[0];    }`

Comment: @Konrad i don't understand your comment, can you detail?

Comment: The array is not a variable but a property of an object. So you have to access it as such. `fct1: () => { return module1.array[0]; }`

Comment: Those aren't modules, they're objects, and the functions in `module2` have the same problem that the functions in the merged object have: They're written with the expectation they *close over* the `array` variable, but there is no `array` variable (there's an `array` property of `module1`), so they fail.

Comment: Separately: If you want to copy the properties of object B into object A, you can use `Object.assign(A, B)`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: array doesn't exist, module1.array does.

Comment: @Wimanicesir Ok, but it does not solve my problem since I expect a single entity that can be sent to another function

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thx, but that does not solve my issue : https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/rxsfvgda/5/

Comment: He never said that Object.assign would solve the issue (hence the word "separately"). You still have to access the property correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you expect the parts of `module2` to be *methods* that can be called on any other (module) object that has an `.array` property. For that, you need to access the array as `this.array`, and you need to use method syntax instead of arrow functions:

```
var module2 = {};
module2.fct1 = function() { return this.array[0]; };
module2.fct2 = function() { return this.array[1]; };
module2.fct3 = function() { return this.array[2]; };
```

or simpler

```
var module2 = {
  fct1() { return this.array[0]; },
  fct2() { return this.array[1]; },
  fct3() { return this.array[2]; },
};
```